# How to Set "Automatically Detect settings" Proxy thru command line?

Tags: windows

I am trying to set "automatically detect settings" using netsh winhttp command. But I could not find a way to set it.

Comment: did you try the netsh winhttp command: "reset proxy"?

Answer (score 12):

You can do it with this:

- To Enable 'Automatically Detect Settings'

  ```
  REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v AutoDetect /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
  ```
- To Disable 'Automatically Detect Settings'

  ```
  REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v AutoDetect /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
  ```

Comment: Tested & worked. This is batch command. I created two .bat files for enabling & disabling.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no global "automatically detect settings" neither a netsh command for this.
the setting is specific to a browser.
i.e. the internet explorer is configured using reg keys.
see the following examples:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819961

once you know the right regkey you can use the reg command to set it.